# How to get the Unmatched data from two table

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, not-exists

How to get the Unmatched data from two table.I want to display the data which is not matched with CostomerMaster table. here is my table structure is

```
CustomerMaster Table:
CusID         int        Unchecked
CName       varchar(MAX) Checked
Caddress    varchar(50)  Checked
Cloacation  varchar(50)  Checked
CMobile     varchar(50)  Checked

DailyDispatch Table:

DailyDispatchID  int    Unchecked
DcNo            varchar(50) Checked
CustID          varchar(50) Checked
Name            varchar(50) Checked
OrderDate       varchar(50) Checked
Gas             varchar(50) Checked
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM   customermaster C WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM   dailydispatch D WHERE  C.CNAME = D.NAME)
```

i am getting the output,but i need to display the output like

```
Name    Gas    OrderDate
```

The problem is how to display in the format,i used joins but not worked out any ideas for sort it out.

Comment: The query you tried doesn't display customers that have data in `dailydispatch` table but the output you want are fields from the `dailydispatch` table? Please be clearer?

Comment: @KenpachiZaraki i want to display from dailydispatch only,but the name from dailydispatch should check with the customermaster table and unmatched data should disply.

Comment: Show some sample data for the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT DD.Name, DD.Gas, DD.OrderDate
FROM   dailydispatch DD full outer join customermaster C on  C.CNAME = DD.NAME)
```

Comment: it displaying null values only

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT D.Name, D.Gas, D.OrderDate FROM DailyDispatch D
Left Join CustomerMaster C On C.CNAME = D.NAME
 And C.CustID Is Null
```